# How should we tell an imaginary story or situation in Japanese?

Tags: tense

In English, when we tell an imaginary story or situation, we use subjective mood, or use simply present or past tenses accordingly.

I wonder how we should tell an imaginary story or situation in Japanese.

We just simply tell them and use tenses accordingly and there is no need to consider things, like mood?

**Example 1**

(We talk about crime. And then I tell an imaginary story and ask what the listener's opinion is.)

> 先週ある人が犯罪を犯して逃げた。さっきその犯人に会って、血がついているナイフを持っているのを見た、今尾行している。何をすればいい？

**Example 2**

(We talk about sci-fi stuff. And then I tell an imaginary story and ask what the listener's opinion is.)

> 先週宇宙人が地球を攻撃した。人類はもう滅亡してしまうから、今何をすればいい？

**Example 3**
(We talk about the Japanese language. And I tell an imaginary situation to explain when to use a word.)

> この言葉はどう使うかについて聞いていますね。例えば、先週あなたの悪口を言った。二日後の今、発見されたけど、私は認めたくない。この時、「破廉恥」という言葉が使えるよ。

**Example 4**

(We talk about the Japanese language. And I tell an imaginary situation to explain when to use a word. But this time the situation happened in the past, and I wonder if this example works)

> この言葉はどう使うかについて聞いていますね。例えば、先週あなたの悪口を言った。二日後、発見されたけど、私は認めたくなかった。その時、「破廉恥」という言葉を使っても通じたはずだったよ。

Answer (score 2):

How about using 「とする。」「としよう。」「として...」「～場合、」「としたら、」「～たら、」 etc. as in...

> 近所で殺人が起こった**とする**。犯人らしき男が血のついた包丁を持って走っているのを見かけ**たら**、(あなたなら)どうする？

> 一週間前に宇宙人が地球を攻撃してきた**としよう**。まもなく人類が滅びる**としたら**、(あなたは)どうする？

> 例えば、先週私があなたの悪口を言った**として**、2日後にそれがバレたのに私がそれを認めようとしない**場合**、「この、恥知らず！」と言うことができます。

<sub>「とする。」「としよう。」 etc. are roughly equivalent to 「と仮定する。」「と仮定しよう。」 etc.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Are my original examples also acceptable as imaginary stories or situations?

Comment: @vincentlin Yes, I think your examples would be understood as imaginary stories (They *could* also be understood as real stories, though.)